# How to make bootstrap caption come on top of the fixed carousel overlay

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a bootstrap website, I need a fixed overlay on the left over which the carousel captions has to slide.

Currently the captions stay under the overlay section. How to fix it.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row fullscreen-carousel">
<div id="main-carousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="banner-seperator">
  </div>
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <!-- First slide -->
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x920" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1 data-animation="animated fadeInDown">
          This is the caption for slide 1
        </h1>
        <p data-animation="animated fadeInUp">
          This is the caption for slide 1
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-animation="animated zoomInUp">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.item -->

    <!-- Second slide -->
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x920" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1 data-animation="animated fadeInDown">
          This is the caption for slide 1
        </h1>
        <p data-animation="animated fadeInUp">
          This is the caption for slide 1
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-animation="animated zoomInUp">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.item -->

    <!-- Third slide -->
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x920" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1 data-animation="animated fadeInDown">
          This is the caption for slide 1
        </h1>
        <p data-animation="animated fadeInUp">
          This is the caption for slide 1
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-animation="animated zoomInUp">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.item -->

  </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#main-carousel"
  role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#main-carousel"
  role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

SCSS

```
.carousel .carousel-caption {
bottom: auto;
text-align: left;
top: 30%;
transform: translateY(-30%);
z-index: 12;
h1 {
  font-size: 6em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
button {
  float: left;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
}

.item {
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.banner-seperator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 27%;
  background-color: $main-banner-bg-color;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Live example here: http://www.bootply.com/f447QYfkHc

I tried placing the overlay before each `.item` It makes the overlay slide with the slider as well. I need the overlay to be fixed to left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem is that you try to bring the caption which is inside an item that is below the banner. I don't think that there is an possibilty to fix this with css.

The only possibility I see is to get the caption outside the .item element.

As a proof for my theory try to add position: relative; z-index: 12; of .item. You will see that the item with the caption gets to the top (but the banner is then overlayed).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to position the caption.

I can see 3 css properties(top,bottom,z-index) which only work for positioned elements.

So specify position (ansolute or relative) and it should work!

Comment: Bootstrap `.caption` already has `position: absolute;` I tried defining position myself as well. Didn't work.